# Value not getting passed in url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

```
 //In Controller this is what I have 
 public class AjaxController : Controller
 {

    [AcceptVerbs(new string[]{"GET"})]
    public ActionResult FindRooms(string selectedBuilding)
    {
        return Json(new { Room = "x"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

 }

 //In Global.asax.cs I have  
 routes.MapRoute
 (
     "AjaxRoute1",
     "Ajax/FindRooms/{selectedBuilding}",
     new { controller = "Ajax", action = "FindRooms", selectedBuilding = "" }
 );
```

If I browse to URL  localhost/Ajax/FindRooms/SOMEBUILDING. The SOMEBUILDING is not getting passed to selectedBuilding parameter of FindRooms method. It is always null?? How can I fix this so that it works in both POST and GET?

Comment: Do you have any other routes registered? Mind the order of route registration, since a more generic route could be used instead of less generic.

Answer (score 0):

As Mr TA suggested the other routes affects this.  The order of routing is important.

I put the default route route at the end and works like a charm.!!

```
        routes.MapRoute
        (
           "AjaxRoute1",
           "Ajax/FindRooms/{selectedBuilding}",
           new { controller = "Ajax", action = "FindRooms", selectedBuilding = "" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute
        (
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

        );
```